# Progress/cancel callback in Tesseract using ETEXT_DESC

Tags: android, c++, tesseract, tess-two

Is there a way to specify a progress and cancel callback in Tesseract? I'm using Tesseract in Android, using the [tess-two project](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two).

There is already a previous question - [Android Tesseract progress callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426683/android-tesseract-progress-callback). However, the answers there imply that it's not possible.

I have another crucial detail to add - I checked the source code **and found a class called `ETEXT_DESC`**, which looks like it can be used for just this purpose.

My question is - can `ETEXT_DESC` be used for progress and cancel callbacks, and if it can, how do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get progress callbacks by implementing the `ProgressNotifier` interface and overriding the `onProgressValues` method. (Behind the scenes, it uses the `ETEXT_DESC` class that you mention.) Provide your notifier object as a parameter to the `TessBaseAPI` constructor.

You can cancel OCR that's in progress using the `stop` method.

I wrote a [blog post](https://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2014/12/17/receiving-ocr-progress-updates-when-using-tesseract-on-android/) about this recently. If you run into problems please open a new issue on the tess-two project.

**EDIT:**

From the blog post:

> The progress percentage can be used in a thermometer-style ProgressBar. The bounding boxes can be drawn on top of the display of the input image during recognition.
>
> Implementing this callback requires using an alternate constructor for the TessBaseAPI object and implementation of the ProgressNotifier interface:

Registering to receive updates:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
 
// Create the TessBaseAPI object, and register to receive OCR progress updates
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI(this);
 
baseApi.getHOCRText(myImage);
```

Receiving the udpates:

```
@Override
public void onProgressValues(ProgressValues progressValues) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progressValues.getPercent());
}
```

Comment: You can also pass in a custom `ProgressNotifier` into the `TessBaseAPI` constructor e.g. `TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI(new TessBaseAPI.ProgressNotifier() {@Override public void onProgressValues(TessBaseAPI.ProgressValues progressValues) {}});`